# Sparseness of 2D set

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

Define the **sparseness** of a set **S** of elements (x, y), with x, y real numbers, to be the minimal real number **d**, satisfying that, for any element **v** in **S**, the closed, punctured-ball centered at **v**, with radius **d**, is non empty (By punctured-ball, that is, the ball not including it's center). It is clear that such a **d** exists, and is unique, if **S** nonempty.

Find the **sparseness** of a given set.

Clearly, we have the naive quadratic-time solution.

Comment: **v** itself always lies in this ball for any positive **d**. Do you mean that there must be at least any *other* point from the set in the ball?

Comment: What is your question?  What is the naive solution you have in hand?

Comment: You could probably reduce it to O(n log n) by putting the points in a quadtree

Comment: @IvanSmirnov Yes, sorry - have clarified to *punctured ball*

Comment: @user3080953 Yes, that was my first thought - but have been trying to find something better

Comment: What is your question? Have you tried anything?

Comment: @JimMischel Please see post for question, comments for attempts

Comment: First, the post poses a problem and you assert that a naive solution exists. Second, you show no attempt to solve the problem. Finally, you did not ask a question. So I'm voting to close as unclear.

Comment: @JimMischel Question is clear (it's even on it's own line), other people seem to have understood it. The two obvious solutions (the O(n^2) one, and the quadtree one) are obvious, and mentioning them only wastes space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the naive solution is to take the distance closest point to each point, and the answer is the maximum of those minimums.

Build an MST (minimum spanning tree) of your points. (Formally, that is the MST of a complete graph, where points are vertices and the weight of an edge it the distance between corresponding points.) MST has a property: for each vertex, the smallest edge incident to it is in the MST. So it is enough to check only edges from the MST to find the answer.

The fastest way to build an MST of a set of points is to build at [Delaunay triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) on it and then find the MST of it using [Kruskal's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm). Both steps take O(n log n) time, and that is the overall running time of the algorithm.

However, building Delaunay triangulation is rather complex, so consider searching for existing libraries rather than coding it from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Clever, I think - but worry about overall speed. Since you mention Delaunay triangulation, and thus probably know more about the space then me, are you familiar with Fortune's algorithm, and if so, can comment about speed? Size of set is about 12 million.

Comment: @Kay I haven't ever used Fortune's algorithm so I can't say anything about its speed. I tried two things: Chan's algorithm for 3D convex hull (Delaunay triangulation can be reduced to it) and some randomized algorithm to build Delaunay triangulation directly (unfortunately, I don't know its name but the idea was to add points one by one in random order and update triangulation locally). Each of them works within couple of seconds for 10^5 points. So if you have 12 million points they'd run in a few minutes. AFAIK Fortune's algorithm is the same order of speed.

Comment: @Kay What do you mean by "best"? The randomized one is simpler to code. They both suffer from collinear points and from large coordinates. I'd recommend to start from searching for a randomized algorithm as it was easier for me to understand.